# Why doesn't this IF statement stop the image from going out of bounds

Tags: c++

I am making a program that copies each individual pixel of a .bmp file onto another, I believe that my `if` statement is trying to keep the image being copied from going out of bounds but isn't working. I'm fairly new to C++ and this is really confusing me.

Note that this is the `button.cc` file, not the `main.cc` I'm 90% certain the problem lies here

```
#include "robot.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "cpputils/graphics/image.h"
#include <string> 

using std::string;; 
using std::endl;  

void Robot::Draw(graphics::Image &my_image) {
  if ((integer % 2) == 0) {
    graphics::Image robot1;
    robot1.Load(fileName1_);
    int width = robot1.GetWidth();
    int height = robot1.GetHeight();

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        graphics::Color color = robot1.GetColor(i, j);
//CHECKS IF ITS OUT OF BOUNDS
        if (i <= my_image.GetWidth() && j <= my_image.GetHeight()) {
            my_image.SetColor(i - x_ + (width / 2), j - y_ + (height / 2),
                              color);
        }
      }
    }
    integer++;
  }
else {
  graphics::Image robot2;
  robot2.Load(fileName2_);
  int width = robot2.GetWidth();
  int height = robot2.GetHeight();

  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      graphics::Color color = robot2.GetColor(i, j);
//CHECKS IF ITS OUT OF BOUNDS
      if (i <= my_image.GetWidth() && j <= my_image.GetHeight()) {
       
          my_image.SetColor(i - x_ + (width / 2), j - y_ + (height / 2), color);
          
        }
      }
    }
    integer++;
  }

}
```

Comment: What are `x_` and `y_`? What values are valid for `SetColor`? Are your sure that your number isn't negative for `i = 0` or `j = 0` or too high for `i == GetWidth()` or `j == GetHeight()`? If you're unsure about any of these questions, then youen you most likely know the right place to look for the issue :)

Comment: What graphics library are you using? SFML?

Answer (score 2):

It's normal in C++ to have ranges between `0` and `count-1`, this is reflected by the for loops with the `i < width` and `j < height` condidions. The same I expect to be true for the `GetWidth()` and `GetHeigth()` member functions of the image class: they give a total amount of valid numbers between `0` and `total_amount-1`.

See here for small examples that can be easily generalized:

`0, 1, 2, 3` are `4` numbers in the range of `0..3`. The `4` itself is not included.

The access via `my_image.SetColor(x, y, c)` can still go out of bounds depending on the values of the (member?) variables `x_` and `y_`.

It's easier to check your out-of bounds checker without real robots and images: concentrate on the combination of min and max values, and since the patterns for x and y are the same, it will be enough to do it for one dimension. So you get at maximum 8 different scenarios, which can even be calculated on paper.

After all, the approach shown to place robots into an image seems to be very inefficient. Most 2D graphic systems provide functions to do these image operations a once. This will look like:

```
robot1.GetImage().Blit(my_image, x, y);
```